# Synching fonts between two macbook pros

Tags: icloud, font

Twice I've tried to address this problem with Apple Support, but they really did not offer much help.

I followed the script below which I got from here which is where you add a folder of your fonts and that way they will automatically sync.

The accepted answer worked for me, too, except that I don't use Dropbox but iCloud. These are instructions, providing that you don't have yet a folder called Fonts in your iCloud storage.

On your Mac:

- Launch Terminal in Applications/Utilities/
- Execute `cd ~/Library` to open your user Library.
- Execute `sudo mv Fonts Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs` to move your Fonts folder to iCloud.
- Enter your password when prompted.
- Run `ln -s Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Fonts` to create a symbolic link in your User Library.

Target Mac:

Launch Terminal in Applications/Utilities/

- Execute `cd ~/Library` to open your user Library.
- Execute `sudo rm -r Fonts` to delete your user fonts folder.
- Enter your password when prompted.
- Execute `ln -s Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Fonts` to create a symbolic link in your User Library.

It is strongly recommended to back up your original fonts!

BTW/ until Big Sur, this technique worked with a subfolder - I didn't need to replace the Fonts folder with a link but just put fonts on iCloud and then made a symbolic link in the Library/Fonts folder called iCloud:

- Execute `cd ~/Library`
- Execute `ln -s Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs/Fonts Fonts/iCloud`

It was less invasive technique but it was getting unstable in Catalina and stopped with macOS 11.

Now I can't even add fonts that are in a Desktop folder to my font book on my personal computer. The funny thing is that I was able to add all of the fonts that I downloaded to my school computer.

My school computer is running Big Sur 11.6. and my personal computer is running Monterey 12.2.1.  Can I "undo" the script that I had used? It seems that that might be the issue since, before that, I could at last add fonts to my font book that I had downloaded.

Comment: How often does the contents of your Font folder change? I'd normally suggest using syncing software, like ChronoSync (or rsync in the Terminal). Or use a font manager like FontExplorerX, which can activate fonts outside the Fonts folder.

Comment: "I followed the script below which I got from here" -- can you please link to the post you copied this from?

Comment: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/312128/how-to-sync-fonts-across-macbooks